# Can i learn Spring MVC directly for web sites rather than basic Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Firstly, I want to know is Spring and Spring MVC different things.

IF they are different then can I jump directly to Spring MVC because I want to build website
and I have very less time to experiment and I want to start as soon possible.

Will spring MVC is sufficient without using hibernate or anything which I need to learn.

I know only core Java.

Comment: If you want to build a website quickly, don't use Java... Java is not a language for quick development.  Go with PHP if you can, then if you have to, write it in Java later.  PHP has barely any learning curve if you can code already and is possibly the fastest web development language as far as product development is concerned (not the fastest in performance admittedly).  If you have any python experience, that would be a good alternative too.

Comment: @Endophenage I would strongly discourage anyone from learning PHP now. If Java is too heavy, go with Ruby/Rails or Groovy/Grails. That's the modern way to do web development.

Answer (score 3):

Spring MVC builds on top of Spring. So you need to know basics of Spring to use Spring MVC. And you doesn't need to learn Hibernate.

**Spring**

- [Introduction to Spring](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364527/Introduction-to-the-Spring-Framework)
- Read chapters 1, 2 and 3 from [reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/)

**Spring MVC**

- [Spring MVC step by step](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)

Comment: +1 - To clarify, "basic Spring" is really Spring IoC / DI, and it is fundamental to all of the Spring technologies, whether you are doing website development or something else.